# Structure of program

Tags: c++

I have few files:

```
main.cpp:
int main{
...
while(1){
...
draw();
...
}
...
return 0;
}
```

and draw.cpp:
I want to see objects and all manipulations here.
I cant make objects local to draw(), because draw() is inside loop,
so I will get many object constructor/destructor calls - so they are global. Also
I ve made init block to prevent unnecessary calls/assignments

```
draw.cpp:
Object A, B;
int initialized = 0;
void draw(){
if(!initialized){
    A.initialization;
    B.initialization;
    initialized = 1;
}
A.move(1,1);
B.rotate(45);
}
```

It works, but Im looking for better way to organize my code

Added:
Thanks for answers, looks like I have to read something about pattern designs

Comment: (1) please don't ask more than one question at a time. (2) is it C or C++

Comment: Global objects aren't on the free store, they're statically allocated.

Comment: If they aren't on the free store, do they cost money to allocate?

Comment: my objects use pointers to free store(dynamic memory)..

Comment: @James: They're come prepaid, courtesy of your loader. :-)

Comment: To me, your second question looks like you're using C++ as a C programmer. There are better designs to achieve what you want to do. Look at factory and manager class designs. Basically all objects that are created will be done via factory, which could use memory-pool, while manager classes are used to manage objects so your draw function needs to only get the instance of the manager classes to retrieve objects and do things. Object manipulation itself, should be dealt separately and not in draw function.

Comment: @all: If you manage your objects with pointers to the free store, then you don't have any destruction problems, because you free the objects manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Define a new Class called Draw and put the attributes into it. You need to modify main and draw files for this. With this you can avoid declaring anything global

**Option 2**

Define a class within draw.cpp called draw and add your current global variables as static member variables. Initialize and use them using static functions. With this you dont have to change main.
This design technique is called Singleton (one of the design patterns)

Example code
draw.cpp

```
class Draw
{
public:
  object A, B;

  static void init()
  {
    // init A
    // init B
    isInitialized = 1;
  }

  static int isInitialized;

  static Object & getA()
  {
     if(isInitialized == 0)
     {
       init();
     } 
     return A;
  }
  // similarly B

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's steps to make it work better:

1. Add a struct containing all your objects near main().
2. pass it to draw(MyStruct &s); via reference parameter.
3. you're done.